# SQLite LIKE parameter is invalid

Tags: sqlite

I have something like the following:

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT c FROM t WHERE r LIKE ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
int error = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 0, "test%", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

When executing this, `error` becomes `SQLITE_RANGE` ("2nd parameter to `sqlite3_bind` out of range"), but I don't have any problem when I use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

The second argument is the index of the SQL parameter to be set. The leftmost SQL parameter has an index of 1.

Comment: Obviously. Sorry, my mistake, I used 1 everywhere **else**.

Comment: It happens to the best of us!